# В чем отличие свойства Класса и свойства конструктора в JS?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, ооп, классы

Есть ли какая-то разница между этими двумя примерами?

```
class Cat {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Steve';
    }
}
```

и

```
class Cat {
    name = 'Steve';
}
```

Казалось бы - во втором случае свойство записывается не в сам объект, а в `Cat.prototype`. Но.. нет. Свойство хранится не в прототипе, а даётся непосредственно объекту, который мы создаём. Получается, различий нет?

Comment: А во втором случае прокатит ```Cat.name```?

Comment: Нет. Вы, как я понял, имели ввиду ```static name```, если внутри класса. Тогда свойство присваивается самому классу, а не создаваемому объекту

Answer (score 3):

Как оказалось, конкретно в данном случае отличий и вправду нет.
Мы добавляем объекту свойства в конструкторе, когда те зависят от передаваемых переменных. Например:

```
class Cat {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

В случае же, когда свойство создаваемого объекта НЕ зависит от передаваемых конструктору переменных, мы можем объявить свойство вне конструктора. Но это вовсе необязательно.

```
class Cat {
    name = 'Steve';
}
```

Либо через конструктор:

```
class Cat {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Steve';
    }
}
```

В данном случае разницы не будет.